# Distributed Source Control - pushing individual changesets

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, dvcs, patch

Working on a bit of a sticky problem and was hoping for some help from the community.  Basically, our dev team is split up into two teams, lets say "Red" and "Blue"

3 repos:
1: Master
2: Red >> Clone of master
3: Blue >> Clone of master

Each developer is cloning red or blue on their local machine where they are working.

Both teams are working on various tasks for our main application.  Each team has a clone of our Shared "Master" Repository on which they are applying their changesets.  The changesets are verified at that level, at which point they are ready to be pushed into the Master.

To simplify, lets say developer A and B are both on Red team.

So the problem comes when developer A pushes changeset 1, then developer B pushes changeset 2.   Then changeset 1 is verified and ready to go into Master but changeset 2 is not.

I want to push changeset 1 to Master as soon as possible, and not wait for verification to changeset 2, especially since changeset 3 could be being introduced in the meantime.

We're currently using mercurial and I like it - I would be willing to switch to git if the workflow for what I want to do would be easier.

Am i thinking about this wrong?  I appreciate the help.

Comment: you have three different trunk and it is confusing. Can you reword your question using maybe trunkRed, trunkBlue, and trunk (for the parent "trunk").

Comment: Would it be too much trouble to make an ascii diagram of your work flow? I'm rather confused.

Comment: Also, if red has changesets a b c, A and B go in. Blue has a b and c, A goes in, but B depends on C from red. Is something magically resolving that kind of dependency prior to anything being pushed?

Answer (score 3):

In the specific case you're describing:

> I want to push changeset 1 to Master
>   as soon as possible, and not wait for
>   verification to changeset 2,
>   especially since changeset 3 could be
>   being introduced in the meantime.

all you need to do is `hg push -r cset1` where *cset1* is the revision number or node hash of the cset you want.

When you push with `-r` it pushes that changes **and all of its ancestors**, so you can push changeset 1 without pushing changeset2, but **not changeset 2 without pushing changeset 1**.

If you need to push them out of order (two but not one) then you're into cherry picking with the TransplantExtension, but so long as you're going in order you've got an easy option.

(Note that to avoid the "two but not one" scenario the best plan is to have whomever wrote feature two do a `hg update zero` first.  That way two and one will be siblings (both kids of zero) rather than parent-child, which more naturally reflects their true relationship, if indeed they are separable features.  This can be done explicitly with branching, but doing it strictly with changeset parentage is a perfectly valid mode of operation too.)

Answer (score 0):

- TeamA
- TeamB
- Master

When `TeamA` is ready to push changes, you merge TeamA into master, and when `TeamB` is ready, you merge TeamB into master.

Periodically down the line both `TeamA` & `TeamB` Should Fetch/Merge from `Master` to make sure thier versions have the latest code.

If you need more examples look at how Gitorious/Github are set up. Each developer has thier own clone of the project, then when they're ready they apply to be merged into the master repo.

This same principle can be applied to Merc, the key is making sure you fetch/merge to the Team Repos (Developer Repos) often to make sure new code is introduced to thier dev cycle.

Comment: The problem with this in HG is its so easy to end up with unresolved heads between merges.

Comment: I understand this - the issue is that I dont really want "red" to have to be stable to push changesets from "red" into trunk.  So i dont want to push the entire clone back into master, just the "cherry-picked" changesets.

Comment: You don't have to pull, it's just best practice for less collision when you merge changesets into trunk.

Comment: Pulling changes back from master isnt the issue - the issue is when there are 2 changesets pushed into Red, and i want to push just one of them into master.  How best do i manage that?  Quilt?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with branching in mercurial, but here's how you'd do it in SVN - i'm sure there's an equivalent. You need to set up branches, and instead merge changesets into /trunk. This allows you to pick and choose which revisions go out, rather than just having to do "svn up" and get them all.

For example, you could have something like

```
/branches/dev
/trunk
```

In this case, /trunk is assumed to be the current stable code, which would run on production. Say you only wanted to push red team's revision 100, and blue team's revision 110. From inside /trunk, you would do:

```
svn merge <host>/branches/dev -r 99:100
svn merge <host>/branches/dev -r 109:110
```

And only the changes made in those specific revisions would be merged into /trunk.

Comment: He's using Mercurial, just explaining in SVN terms, which is  completely confusing. I don't think he's using branches.

Comment: I know, but as I'm unfamiliar with Mercurial syntax, I thought I'd at least try and convey the idea of branching and merging. His scenario is exactly what branches are for.

Comment: @Tim, while I agree trying to answer it in SVN is confusing, I think he may have a point about branches. Especially if TeamA and TeamB are really just different features being implemented. No need for multiple repos, just team/feature branches.

Comment: Well - in mercurial and git, a clone of the repo basically is a branch.