# In Mercurial, is there any way (aside from "Cherry picking") to push a changeset without also pushing changesets associated with a different head?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, dvcs

In the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768112/distributed-source-control-pushing-individual-changesets), [Ry4an](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8992/ry4an) states that "you cannot push Changeset2 without pushing Changeset1".

This certainly makes sense if the repository looks like this:

```
+ Changeset2
|
+ Changeset1
|
+ Original
```

However it doesn't seem to make as much sense in the following scenario, which is what I currently have:

```
+ Changeset2
|
|   + Changeset1
|  /
| /
+ Original
```

Ideally, I want to be able to push just Changeset2 back to the repository I initially cloned from. Mercurial doesn't seem willing to let me do that. It's insisting I push Changeset 1 also... which is not allowed as it would create a new head in the original repository. Obviously I could "Cherry pick", or create a patch to apply on the original repository but that seems clunky. Am I missing something?

**Update:** I should probably have mentioned in my initial question that I was trying to perform the operation from the [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) GUI. As [Niall C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19465/niall-c). correctly identified in his answer, the Mercurial command line allowed me to accomplish what I needed, however I would still be interested in learning if there is any way to accomplish the same operation from the GUI.

Comment: Yup, in that question the history was linear and my answer was specific to that.  Naill has exactly what you need below.

Comment: Regarding your update, there is a way to do this in TortoiseHg, but it can't really be treated as a default behavior: you have to manually choose which branches to push every time you push. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819760/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're using `hg push` without any command-line option, it will try to push every changeset in your local repository that doesn't exist in the remote repository.  If you use the `-r` / `--rev` option, it will just push that revision and its ancestors.  In your case, you would need to do:

```
hg push --rev Changeset2
```

See `hg help push` for full details.

Comment: Excellent! I was sure I must be missing something and that was it.

Comment: Check out Steve Losh's `hg nudge` command (http://hgtip.com/tips/advanced/2009-09-28-nudge-a-gentler-push/). It's the same idea, but he has some nice explanations and workflows you can use with it.

Answer (score 2):

For the UI lovers who like pictures:

1. In TortoiseHg click on `Detect outgoing changes to` button.
   [image]
2. Click right mouse button on revision you want to push.
3. Choose `Push -> Push to Here`.
   [image]

Result: You will push only revision selected rather than everything.
[image]

Hope this saves you some time.