# For Mercurial, can we push some changesets and don't push some?

Tags: mercurial

If we committed several times, for example, on our local repo, for revision 3000, 3001, 3002, 3003.  If we push to a remote repo, it will push 3000 to 3003.  Is there a way to push only 3000 and 3001?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Mercurial, is there any way (aside from "Cherry picking") to push a changeset without also pushing changesets associated with a different head?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979122/in-mercurial-is-there-any-way-aside-from-cherry-picking-to-push-a-changeset)

Answer (score 42):

Yes, you can select a revision to push.  `hg push -r 3001` (all ancestors of the chosen revision will be pushed; you don't need to specify 3000.)

Comment: great, thanks, went and saw the docs.  it says if `-r` is used, then that changeset and all its ancestors will be pushed.  so it probably is not possible to just push 3002 and 3003 without 3000 and 3001?

Comment: You're correct.  You can't send 3002 without sending 3001 also (unless they already have 3001, of course).  You can send a different changeset that has the same change but a different hash and parent (and is thus a totally different changeset), but doing that too often means you'll end up with duplicate work in your repos.

Comment: Also, if using tortoise hg: after clicking 'detect outgoing changesets', right click the revision you want to push and click push->push selected branch

Comment: You can send revision 3002 without sending 3001 if you reorder your history using `hg histedit -r3001`.  Of course, you have to enable the histedit extension in your `.hgrc` first.

Answer (score 9):

If you need to push some changesets without all ancestors (solution described in [@Woolble's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016087/for-mercurial-can-we-push-some-changesets-and-dont-push-some/4016133#4016133)), a good option is to use Mercurial Queues extension (MQ).

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MqExtension

This will let you re-order and even combine changesets so you can push them in whatever order you like. It takes a bit of work to get started but you'll find it well worth the effort.

I've TortoiseHg makes working with MQ pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 8):

For those who are using UI and like pictures:

1. [In TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/download/) click on `Detect outgoing changes to` button.
   [image]
2. Click right mouse button on revision you want to push.
3. Choose `Push -> Push to Here`.
   [image]

Result: You will push only revision selected rather than everything.
[image]

Hope this saves you some time.